# Loading files in exrm release

Tags: elixir, exrm

I'm using an html file as a template with the following code, working in dev mode (not in an exrm release):

```
{:ok, template} = File.read "priv/static/templates/receipt_template.html"
```

When the release is packaged with exrm, this relative path is no longer valid and the file can't be found.  Is there a better way to declare the path, so that it won't get messed up when this is turned into a release?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Path.join("#{:code.priv_dir(:your_app_name)}", "static/templates/receipt_template.html")` to get the correct path. I would recommend always using this because it is guaranteed to work regardless of environment.